# Как сделать выборку where id = and id = из связанной таблицы в laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Есть продукты и фильтры, они связаны через смежную таблицу продукты_фильтры.

Как получить продукты, где id фильтра = 1 и id фильтра = 2 ?

```
  $products = Product::whereHas('attributeValue', function ($q){
                $q->where('id', 3);
                $q->where('id', 5);
    })->get();
```

Пытался таким способом, но в ответ получаю пустую коллекцию.

Comment: $q->whereIn('id', [3,5])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На чистом SQL это будет

```
SELECT product.id
FROM product
WHERE product.filter_id IN (3, 5)
GROUP BY product.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product.filter_id) = 2
```

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но WHERE product.filter_id IN (3, 5) говорит нам о том, что sql должен вернуть продукты, которые принадлежат к одному из перечисленных Id, а мне нужно, чтобы продукт принадлежал в связанной таблице и к id 3, и к id 5

Comment: @Sentim *Могу ошибаться, но* Всё верно, но на этом WHERE запрос не закончился. Дальше есть ещё две инструкции - постарайтесь теперь понять, что они сделают с отобранными WHERE записями.

Comment: Черт, я почему-то категорически решил не замечать эти инструкции. Спасибо за помощь.